# any Idea howto flip a Mesh to generate an Object?

Tags: opengl, sdl, glut

I try to reduce a very complex Mesh (reduce the objectdata in file itself).
For example: A Human Body. I want to cut it in half, and save only the half mesh-data on disk (wavefront obj). 
Now i want to read the Data, push it to a Renderlist, and than... mirror/double it by code.
But how? ;-) Is there a simple way to do this?

I searched SE and youtube, but found only stuff on flip normals.

Comment: Are you asking how to compute the whole mesh from the half saved mesh on CPU, or do you want to know how to push only half a mesh to GPU and then render that twice in different positions?

Answer (score 2):

Scale the mesh by -1 1 1 (to mirror through the x axis), and reverse the face winding via glFrontFace. For example in old school OpenGL:

```
drawObject();
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(-1, 1, 1);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
drawObject();
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glPopMatrix();
```

If you are using shaders, the apply the local scaling to your mvp matrix. To mirror the model through the y axis, use a scale of 1 -1 1, and similarly a scale of 1 1 -1 for the z axis.

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm.